# include and use scalaz with eclipse ide

Tags: eclipse, scala, scalaz

I try to use scalaz library in eclipse ide. I download scalaz-full_2.9.1-6.0.4.jar and go to project properties in java build tab and scalaz-full_2.9.1-6.0.4.jar to external jar.

Then i write:

```
import scalaz._
```

in my scala file and got error:

**not found: value scalaz**

How can i correctly include scalaz lib to my project?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you have to include the inner jars (like scalaz-core_2.9.1-6.0.4.jar).

Comment: Thank you for reply. Where can i got scalaz-core ... ?

Comment: It's inside scalaz-full_2.9.1-6.0.4.jar (in the folder scalaz_2.9.1-6.0.4).

Answer (score 1):

import :

```
import scalaz._
import Scalaz._
```

Maven dependencies :

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.scalaz</groupId>
        <artifactId>scalaz-core_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>7.1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.scalaz</groupId>
        <artifactId>scalaz-effect_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>7.1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>                
        <groupId>org.scalaz</groupId>
        <artifactId>scalaz-scalacheck-binding_2.9.3</artifactId>
        <version>7.1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.scalaz</groupId>
        <artifactId>scalaz-typelevel_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>7.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

I took these dependencies from sbt section of Scalaz tutorial http://eed3si9n.com/learning-scalaz/sbt.html